# The $\min(\cdots ,\cdots)$ function

Tags: maxima-minima

I have a question (might turn out silly, but I am missing something!) based on the minimum function.

> Does $|x-y|+|y-z|\ge |x-z| \implies \min(|x-y|,1)+\min(|y-z|,1)\ge \min (|x-z|,1)\ \ \ ?$

$x,y,z\in \Bbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by just grinding through the cases:

Suppose $a,b $ are non negative. Then
$\min(a+b,1) \le \min(a,1)+\min(b,1)$.

To see this:

If $a+b \le 1$, then both $a,b$ are also, and the formula follows.

If $a+b >1$, then suppose that either of $a,b$ is $\ge 1$, then the formula
follows. Otherwise, $a,b$ are both $<1$ in which case
$\min(a+b,1) = 1 < a+b = \min(a,1)+\min(b,1)$.

Then we have
$\min(|x-z|,1) \le \min(|x-y|+|y-z|,1) \le \min(|x-y|,1)+\min(|y-z|,1)$.

Comment: Nice use of triangle inequality..in the last step

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that
$\min(a+b, c)
\le \min(a, c)+\min(b, c)
$
where
$a \ge 0, b \ge 0,
c > 0$.

If you use
$\min(u, v)
=\dfrac{u+v-|u-v|}{2}
$,
you get
(using $c$ instead of $1$)
$\min(a+b, c)
=\dfrac{a+b+c-|a+b-c|}{2}
$
and
$\min(a, c)+\min(b, c)
=\dfrac{a+c-|a-c|}{2}+\dfrac{b+c-|b-c|}{2}
=\dfrac{a+b+2c-|a-c|-|b-c|}{2}
$.

So we want
$a+b+c-|a+b-c|
\le a+b+2c-|a-c|-|b-c|
$
or
$|a-c|+|b-c|
\le c+|a+b-c|
$.

It would be nice
if this could be proved
using the triangle inequality,
but I have not been able
to do this.
So,
I will resort to cases,
which sort of
removes the reason
for doing this
in the first place.
Oh, well.

Assume that
$a \ge b$,
since this is
symmetrical in $a$ and $b$.

If $b \ge c$,
this is
$a-c+b-c
\le c+a+b-c
$
or
$c \ge 0$,
which is true.

If $a \ge c \ge b$,
this is
$a-c+c-b
\le c+a+b-c
$
or
$b \ge 0$,
which is true.

Note that
if we allow
$b < 0$,
the inequality can be false.
If
$a=2, b=-1$,
and $c = 1$,
then
$\min(a,c)+\min(b, c)
=1-1
=0
$
and
$\min(a+b, c)
=1
$.

Finally,
if
$c \ge a \ge b$,
this is
$c-a+c-b
\le c+|a+b-c|
$
or
$c 
\le a+b+|a+b-c|
$.

There are a final two cases
depending on how
$c$ compares with
$a+b$.

If
$c \le a+b$,
this is
$c \le a+b+a+b-c$
or
$2c \le 2(a+b)$,
which is true.

If
$c \ge a+b$,
this is
$c 
\le a+b+c-a-b
=c
$
which is true.

Sort of annoying that
I have to go through
all these cases.

Comment: Thanks for taking so much pain. I thought that there would be some simpler proof/disproof of the statement but it seems not.. +1 :-)